# Как упростить повторяющийся код?

Tags: java, android

Проект игра крестики нолики... игра происходит против телефона (используется алгоритм с помощью которого можно играть против телефона).. внизу представлена код для первой кнопки.. в игре 9 кнопок.. ВОПРОС! Как можно делать код поменьше, упростить, потому что это не чистый код

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
     if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
         btn1click();
         endgame();

         Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               super.run();
               Game_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            int a = new Random().nextInt(3);
                            if (btn2.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn8clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn2.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn7clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn9clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn6clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn4.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn6clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn4.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn2.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn8clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn2clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn7clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn3clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn4.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn6clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn4clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn9clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn3clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn4.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn4clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn3clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn9clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn8clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn2clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn2.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn9clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn7clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn6clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn6.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn3clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn8clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn7clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn2.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn3clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn3.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn2clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn4.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn7clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn7.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn4clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn9clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (btn1.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn9.getText().toString().equals("X") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                btn5clicko();
                                endgame();
                            } else if (a == 0) {
                                if (btn2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn2clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn4clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn5clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn3clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn6clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn7clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn8clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn9clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                }
                            } else if (a == 1) {
                                if (btn4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn4clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn2clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn5clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn3clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn6clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn7clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn8clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn9clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                }
                            } else if (a == 2) {
                                if (btn5.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn5clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn4.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn4clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn2clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn3clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn6.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn6clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn7.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn7clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn8.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn8clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                } else if (btn9.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    btn9clicko();
                                    endgame();
                                }
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(550);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

для начала надо попробовать его сократить.

начнем с того, что `endgame();` вызывается всегда (вроде), если я  прав эту команду можно вынести в конец, а не дублировать.

---

в `if` вы всегда проверяете 2 кнопки на соответствие одному символу и ещё одну на пустоту. Это можно вынести в отдельный метод, передавать туда 3 кнопки и символ -> возвращать `boolean`

пример:
создать метод

```
private boolean checkCombination(Button first, Button second, Button therd, char symbol){

    return first.getText().toString().equals(symbol) && 
           second.getText().toString().equals(symbol) && 
           therd.getText().toString().equals("");

}
```

с этим методом ваш if сокращается с такого:

```
if (btn2.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn5.getText().toString().equals("O") && btn8.getText().toString().equals(""))
```

до такого

```
if(checkCombination(btn2, btn5, btn8, 'O'))
```

нормальное название для метода потом придумаете =)

---

логику выбора кнопок можно разделить на 2 этапа:

- проверка на "О"
- проверка на "Х"

их можно засунуть в цикл. Код сократиться примерно в 2 раза

---

Сделайте пока так и выложите обновленный код, посмотрим, что ещё можно сократить. Только на каждом этапе проверяйте работоспособность кода, а лучше напишите сейчас тесты и только потом рефакторьте

Comment: когда то я только endgame() вынес в конец, и что-то стало не работать, поэтому сделал таким образом... ща еще раз попробую сократить, убрать endgame(), смотрю че получится....  А вот немного не понял тут эти дела, ну в смысле  вынести в отдельный метод, передавать туда 3 кнопки и символ и цикл... если не сложно можете привести пример?

Comment: @name_surname дополнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Кусок кода вырван из контекста. Если вы все написали в таком стиле, то боюсь, что изменение только этого метода Вам не поможет...

В этом коде можете только постоянно повторяющийся  `endgame()` вынести за пределы условий. Но это не вариант. Ваш подход в корне неверный. У вас есть 9 кнопок, вешаете слушатель на каждую, в слушателе только три метода - `validate`, `setText`, и метод типа `detectWin`. Первый проверяет занято ли указанное поле. Для этого возьмите `getText` кнопки в слушателе и посмотрите , есть ли там какое-то значение. Второй меняет текст кнопки на крестик либо нолик. Третий проверяет , одержал ли кто-то победу либо исход игры - ничья.

В качестве игрового поля используйте 2 обычных массива 3х3, хранящих `boolean`. Туда записывайте все ходы. Один массив для ноликов, второй для крестиков. Третий метод обращается именно к этому массиву и проверяет выигрышные комбинации. Ничью можно определить по общему количеству сделанных ходов. Выигрышные комбинации определить достаточно просто проходом по массиву с помощью 2 вложенных циклов. В принципе, можно обойтись и одним массивом, тут уже как вам проще. Вот и все...

Метод для проверки победной комбинации

```
public static boolean arrayCalc(boolean[][] array) {

    boolean resultArray[] = new boolean[array.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] == false) resultArray[i] = true;
            if (array[i][j] == false) resultArray[array.length + j] = true;
        }
    }

    for (boolean b : resultArray) {
        if (b == false) return true;
    }
    if (array[0][0]==true && array[1][1]==true && array[2][2]==true) return true;
    if (array[0][2]==true && array[1][1]==true && array[2][0]==true) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Просто для меня немного сложно)) можете пример привести

Comment: Пример игры крестики-нолики?)) Я вам описал общий алгоритм. Сложность может возникнуть только с проверкой на победу. Ну этот метод я вам для примера напишу. Передаете туда игровое поле - массив 3х3 и получаете true в случае, если обнаружена победная комбинация и false, если таковой нет. Задавайте вопросы конкретнее, тогда и отвечу конкретнее